# Inverse of Fourier transformed image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

why i cant get the inverse of the image that i converted using Fourier transform and image processing? the code for the program is as below.here the image is being converted via image processing but i cannot get the inverse image back.pls help me

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
a=imread('lenna.png');
j=rgb2gray(a)
figure,imshow(a);
figure,imshow(j);
p=size(j);
[x,y]=size(j);
n1=rand(220,220);
b=exp(2*pi*i*n1);
k=fft2(j);
c=k.*b;
d=fft2(c);
figure,imshow(d);
s=size(d);
[r,t]=size(d);
n2=rand(220,220);
e=exp(2*pi*i*n2);
f=fft2(e);
figure,imshow(f);
g=fft2(f);
h=conj(e);
i=g.*h;
k=ifft(i);
figure,imshow(k);
```

Comment: Please at least put comments in your code! Also explain what goes wrong and where

Comment: Surely you need `ifft2` rather than `ifft`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things wrong with the code and the objective is not clear. Most critically you are multiplying mismatched matrices in frequency space. If your goal is to add noise to the image spectrum, you can do something like this:

```
a=imread('lenna.png');
j=rgb2gray(a);
p=size(j);
n1=0.01*rand(p);
k=fft2(j);
figure,imshow(k);
c=k.*n1;
d=ifft2(c);
figure,imshow(d);
```

To recover the "signal" that was dumped on the image in frequency space, just repeat the previous step with the corrupted and original files: (1) FFT both, (2) take the ratio, (3) do whatever you want with the remainder, which is the "signal" you originally dumped on the image:

```
a=imread('lenna.png');
j=rgb2gray(a);
b =imread('corruptedlenna.png');
j2=rgb2gray(b);
% assume a and b are same size, otherwise the following needs to be changed
p=size(j);
k=fft2(j);
k2=fft2(j2);
messg = k2./k;
```

Comment: ya this was what i was looking for can u pls tell me how to get the old image back

Comment: Do you mean how to filter away the noise?

Comment: yaaa i want to get the noice out of it

Comment: actally my objectve is to do the random phase encoding and decoding of that image.can u pls tell me the code for that

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but to retrieve the information you encoded onto the image you can see my addition to the answer.

Comment: @SidharthaRamachandran If this answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting it